# Trying to use jQuery and JavaScript to delete an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a simple to-do list in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery and am trying to set up a task that when you drag it to the drop location it will ask the user to confirm that they want to delete their task, and then delete it.

However I keep getting a syntax error that says that I'm missing a } after the property list, plus I can't work out how to make the task get deleted! Here is my code::

```
<script>
$("#draggable").draggable();

$("#deleteBox").droppable( {
    drop: function(ui, event) {
        var deleted = confirm("Confirm delete.");
    }
    if(deleted === true) {
        alert("Deleted");
    }
})
</script>

<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<div class="boxes" id="todo">
    <h3>Create Task</h3>
    <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Task Name"><br/>
    <input id="subject" type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date Due ##/##/####"><br/>
    <textarea id="inputBox"></textarea>
    <div id="deleteBox">Drag your task here to delete it.</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="boxes" id="tasks">
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
    <div id="draggable">
        <p>Subject</p>
        <p>Due Date</p>
        <textarea>Description</textarea>
        <input type="radio" name="inProgress" value="In Progress">In Progress
        <input type="radio" name="completed" value="Completed">Completed

    </div>
</div>
<div class="boxes" id="inProgress">
    <h3>In Progress</h3>
</div>
<div class="boxes" id="completed">
    <h3>Completed</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You sure your jquery src is "jquer-" instead of "jquery-"?

Comment: your `if` needs to be inside the `drop` function. Otherwise it breaks the object syntax and will certainly throw errors

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to JavaScript and I realized that within a minute of posting this question.

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this question, as well as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us look at your .droppable, which contains the "drop" listener. In this, you have a function where you assign a confirm response to a local variable. You won't be able to access this outside the listener. This is most likely why you are having issues with your if statement.

I would suggest putting that little bit of code inside the drop listener like so:

```
drop: function (ui, event) {
    var deleted = confirm("Confirm delete.");
    if(deleted)
        alert("Deleted!");
}
```

You could also make a second listener, either 'deactivate' or 'activate' and check if items are deleted in those listeners. You can find more info here [JQuery UI Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

[I've set up a simple Fiddle with my answer. (click this line)](http://jsfiddle.net/49L5fgdw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#deleteBox").droppable( {
    drop: function(ui, event) {
        var deleted = confirm("Confirm delete.");
    }
    if(deleted === true) {
        alert("Deleted");
    }
})
```

This code

```
if(deleted === true) {
    alert("Deleted");
}
```

is in invalid place, cause function is closed and you are putting it in object declaration...